# How to treat income earned in 2 diff countries during the same period

Tags: income-tax, india

For the FY 2015-2016, I have earned salary income in India from my company for which TDS was deducted. I keep visiting Dubai and earn salary income there as well which gets credited to my Dubai bank account.

For the period mentioned above I was out of India for more than 182 days, till date I have not transferred any money from Dubai to my India account.
Now my question is
1. Do I need to declare the income I have earned in Dubai?
2. Do I need to change my residential status ?
3. Will the income I have earned in Dubai is taxable ?
4. Any other thing I need to be aware of

Answer (score 1):

> I keep visiting Dubai

Not sure what kind of work it is, assuming it regular job.

> For the period mentioned above I was out of India for more than 182 days,

If you were out of India for more than 182 days in a given financial year then you would NRI for tax purposes.

> till date I have not transferred any money from Dubai to my India account.

Whether you have transferred the money or not is not relevant for tax purposes. Your status [NRI / Resident] is relevant.

> Do I need to declare the income I have earned in Dubai?

No you are not required to as your status is NRI. You are required to file a return on the income [Salary/Interest/gains/etc] accruing in India.

> Do I need to change my residential status ?

Not sure where you are wanting to change this.

> Will the income I have earned in Dubai is taxable ?

As you are NRI, the income earned outside of India is not taxable in India. From a tax point of view, it does not matter whether you keep the funds in Dubai or transfer it back to India.

Edit:
The [Income Tax rules](http://www.incometaxindia.gov.in/_layouts/15/dit/pages/viewer.aspx?grp=act&cname=cmsid&cval=102120000000037028&opt=&isdlg=1) are not very clear if your wife can claim for her father-in-law. Best consult a CA. For quite a few regulations, Wife's father-in-law are treated at par with father.

Comment: Thanks Dheer ..... On small doubt as NRI can I claim deduction under section 80dd for the income earned in India

Comment: 80D yes. 80 DD no for NRI

Comment: Can my wife Claim deduction in 80dd for my father ( her father in law )